# Questions about how to find a writer to write a specific thing for me

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I really want to ask [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13857/where-to-hire-a-scenario-writer-for-a-small-interactive-story-game) somewhere where is a chance for it to be answered.

But such questions are explicitly marked off-topic here, in the Writers.SE FAQ.

Please advise, is there a place where my question would be on-topic? :-)

Or maybe I can rephrase the question somehow, so it would be on-topic here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm... that's a tough one.

The FAQ entry was meant to prevent people from using this site as a job board; as written the question you linked to is borderline for us.  If it were re-written something like this it would be on-topic here:

> I'm a non-writer working on an interactive fiction project that will be used to demo a particular software product our company has created.  We've tried finding the "right" story to use or the right person to write for us using XYZ-method, but it was unsuccessful because of ZYX-reason.
>
> How can we better locate and attract someone to do this sort of writing work for us in fluent, native English, despite being in a country (Russia) with a shortage of native English speakers (let alone writers)?

Basically, rather than explaining the terms you are looking for or what exactly you want to license (which is borderline as far as our trying to avoid job-board-like postings), explain *how you are trying to interact with and attract writers* and  seek advice for a better strategy.  That keeps it about the professional side of writing, rather than a specific company's specific needs.

Comment: correct, in other words, make it general so it can benefit future visitors who have similar problems... at least in *some* small way: [ask]

Answer (score 3):

SE sites are, by intention, not job boards.

What I think *would* be appropriate would be:

> What good online job boards exist where I could find a writer for this type of task?

Even this, IMHO, seems more appropriate to GameDev.SE than on Writers.SE; but it would probably be fine on either.

Comment: Aha! "Online job board" are the words I looked for. Thanks.